# Some help querying third normal form

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have three tables. One is of people, the second of meetings and the third of attendance (linking people to meetings). In detail, the tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `people` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attend` (
  `people_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `meeting_id` int(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `meeting` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I cannot get my head around the SQL required to step through each person and list everyone they've met with.

I've only been able to work out how to climb in one direction with the SQL

```
SELECT people.name, meeting.id FROM people LEFT JOIN attend ON people_id = people.id LEFT JOIN meeting ON meeting_id = meeting.id
```

Help with an explanation would be appreciated enormously.

Comment: Please list your table structure along with the query you've tried so far.

Comment: What format would be best to list the table structure?

Comment: Well, the best thing IMHO would be to list your 'create table' statements. That way, we get all the constraints etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct p1.name, p2.name
from people p1, people p2, attend a1, attend a2, meeting m
where p1.id = a1.people_id
  and p2.id = a2.people_id
  and a1.meeting_id = m.id
  and a2.meeting_id = m.id
  and p1.id <> p2.id
```

or bypassing the meeting table:

```
select distinct p1.name, p2.name
from people p1, people p2, attend a1, attend a2
where p1.id = a1.people_id
  and p2.id = a2.people_id
  and a1.meeting_id = a2.meeting_id
  and p1.id <> p2.id
```

Comment: Fantastic! I came close to this, but never included with p1 <> p2!

Answer (score 3):

Your table design is good - you'll be able to do whatever you want when you store information that way.

Since you have a reciprocal relationship, your initial reports will have redundancies unless you take steps to remove them. By this I mean that if Fred meets Mary at meeting #1, then Mary meets Fred at the same meeting. So the first solution, below, lists everybody twice -- but it is useful if you want to be able to find anyone in your person list and list who they met:

```
SELECT  distinct p1.name, 'met', p2.name, 'at', a1.meeting_id
FROM people as p1
    JOIN attend as a1 on a1.people_id = p1.id
    JOIN attend as a2 on a2.meeting_id = a1.meeting_id
    JOIN people as p2 on p2.id = a2.people_id
where p1.id <> p2.id
order by a1.meeting_id;

+------+-----+------+----+------------+
| name | met | name | at | meeting_id |
+------+-----+------+----+------------+
| Mary | met | Fred | at |          1 |
| Fred | met | Mary | at |          1 |
| Eric | met | Mary | at |          2 |
| Mary | met | Eric | at |          2 |
+------+-----+------+----+------------+
```

You see what I mean about listing everybody twice. If you sort by either p1.name or p2.name, you'll group together the people so everybody that "Mary" met will be together in the list.

But you can do other things, depending on how the program using your queries is going to work.

```
SELECT p.name, (SELECT group_concat(name) 
    FROM people as p1 
    JOIN attend as a1 on a1.people_id = p1.id
    JOIN attend as a2 on a2.meeting_id = a1.meeting_id
    WHERE a2.people_id = p.id
      AND p.id <> p1.id)
FROM people as p
ORDER by p.name;

+------+-----------+
| name | People    |
+------+-----------+
| Eric | Mary      |
| Fred | Mary      |
| Mary | Fred,Eric |
+------+-----------+
```

This is less efficient (which may or may not matter to you) but you get a list for each person of who they met. You can expand that query to list the meeting(s) at which they met, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
select p1.name as name1, p2.name as name2
from attend a1
inner join attend a2
  on a2.meeting_id = a1.meeting_id
  and a2.people_id > a1.people_id
inner join people p1
  on p1.id = a1.people_id
inner join people p2
  on p2.id = a2.people_id
```

In the above, we're using inner joins to get the fields that we want from people and are using a2.people_id > a1.people_id to avoid listing the same metting twice